# command prompt closes after the command ? how to stop it?

Tags: python, operating-system

i am running this command using python idle on windows . but command promt closes just after the command is executed.How to stop it?

```
import os
os.system('ipconfig')
```

Comment: it does the same if you type the command in `Run` in Windows

Comment: Once the program is done, then there is no need for it to stay open. Try to type your command in a python shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a window to show the output, the easiest way is to put python to sleep for some time.

```
import os
import time

os.system('ipconfig')
time.sleep(999)
```

In this case the window will stay open for 999 seconds.

But in most cases it's best to open a python console for a live session.

Answer (score 0):

This should pause the windows console until you hit a key:

```
import os
os.system('ipconfig & pause')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the command is running successfully, your question would be better served by a little context; why do you want to run ipconfig from within the Idle shell? If you want to capture the information in python, you should book up on the `subprocess` module.

To answer your question as asked, in an Idle shell in Windows (tested on Win 7) the following will open a CMD window which will remain open until you close it or type EXIT.

```
    >>> import os
    >>> os.system('CMD /K IPCONFIG')
```